# The association bonus will trigger another 100 points?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts, association, association-bonus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've just received 100 points association bonus to all my Stack Exchange accounts since gathered more than 200 points on one of them. Now as a result of this bonus, some of my other accounts went beyond 200 points also. Should this trigger additional 100 points bonus for all accounts or only the first account which reached the 200 gives it?

Comment: that would be great. Quite a pity that it doesn't work that way

Comment: @lunboks The only related thing there is that "it awarded a maximum of one time per site". However my question is till legitimate..

Comment: @EugeneS Well, IMO that answers your question. If the +100 bonus is only awarded once, then that means you won't get it again if another account reaches 200.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I had the same question. I voted up for you here as this is a good question.

Comment: It's a pity that it was marked as a duplicate, because the question which was considered duplicate of this one is entirely different. This is a very specific question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can get the bonus only once. You will get 100 reputation to both existing and new accounts that are linked to the one with >200 reputation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However still, it says that this bonus is give once PER SITE. So if the +100 bonus caused on of the sites to go beyond it seems logical to grant the bonus again.

Comment: You get the bonus once per site, but it is also only triggered once.

Comment: @EugeneS: I assume it means once per _receiving_ site (since that's how it works).  So you'll get the +100 rep bonus on each of your accounts (and will continue to get it on each new account you sign up for), but once you've got it once, that account won't get it again.